# Samba share external USB device

Tags: 12.04, samba, ntfs

I managed to share stuff from my Ubuntu 12.04 to my private network, and the data is visible from a Windows machine. I even shared a hdd that has windows on it. So everything seems to work fine.

When I want to share a mounted device (USB pen drive, USB HDD... etc) however, I get from the Windows machine: **Access denied on file \...**

I realize that this is due to the missing rights on the mounted folder. By default a mounted folder gets the equivalent of **700 : drwx------**, and the owner myself. But, I can't seem to change the rights on the external device... they remain 700.

Is there a special trick I need  to do in order to share NTFS mounted usb devices?

Thanks

P.S. from this [Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/113650/windows-users-unable-to-access-samba-share-of-an-external-drive) I see that NTFS devices can not be shared....is this true? It's a bit strange, because I have in my PC 2 HDD's with 3 NTFS partitions, and I can share them without a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, if anybody cares:

The external NTFS drive mounts with me as owner and with 700 permissions, meaning that only I can access it. I found a tip on the ubuntu forums from [Morbius1](http://ubuntuforums.org/member.php?u=982144) that I can force the incoming connection to look like me by adding the following line in /etc/samba/smb.conf, in the shared section:

```
force user = your-user-name
```

It works great.

Comment: This worked, however I use my system as `root`. Is there a trick to changing the mounting privileges and owner. I am worried about all users having root privileges